# How to make massive selection SAP ABAP

Tags: sql, select, abap, database-cursor

I am doing a massive selection from database with the intention of saving it on application server or local directory.
Since the db has loads of entries I first tried this way:

```
SELECT * FROM db PACKAGE SIZE iv_package
    INTO CORRESPONDING FIELDS OF TABLE rt_data
    WHERE cond  IN so_cond
    AND   cond1 IN so_cond1.

SAVE(rt_data). 
ENDSELECT.
```

This resulted in a dump, with the following message:

> Runtime Errors:         DBIF_RSQL_INVALID_CURSOR
>   Exeption      :         CX_SY_OPEN_SQL_DB

I tried doing an alternative way as well:

```
 OPEN CURSOR WITH HOLD s_cursor FOR
  SELECT * FROM db
    WHERE cond  IN so_cond
    AND   cond1 IN so_cond1.
  DO.
    FETCH NEXT CURSOR s_cursor INTO TABLE rt_data PACKAGE SIZE iv_package.

    SAVE(rt_data).
ENDDO.
```

This also resulted in a dump with the same message.

What is the best approach to this scenario?

Comment: Are you explicitely commiting in the meantime? This runtime error happens if you execute `COMMIT WORK` or `COMMIT WORK AND WAIT` between `SELECT` and `ENDSELECT` or in your `DO ENDO.` loop with cursor. Commiting simply invalidates the cursor.

Comment: Nope, I am not. The save method only converts the table to a table of strings and then it uses `GUI_DOWNLOAD`

Comment: Then there has to be a commit somwhere inside `GUI_DOWNLOAD` then. Let me check that and I will get back to you. If it is like that, then the only way of using that stuff will be diving the data into packages based on a primary key of this table. How is the primary key of your database table built. Is it GUID?

Comment: Yes, I just checked and it is due to `GUI_DOWNLOAD`. 
That basically means I cannot use cursor or `SELECT` `ENDSELECT`?

How would be the best way to do this? This db contains millions of entries and needs to be extracted into excel files. The primary key is formed by 8 fields, being this fields numericals and chars.

Comment: Is it better to `SELECT` the data from the DB all at once and then split it? And if so, is there a way to dynamically declare internal tables?

Comment: I do not think it is better to select it all at once. Let me see if there is a parameter that switches off this commiting in `GUI_DOWNLOAD`. If not it would be better to get the minimum and the maximum value of the primary key and then split it into n packages and select it in that way without opening a cursor.

Comment: Do you select that data from a standard SAP table? If so, could you give me the name of it, so that I can propose a solution?

Comment: No, it's not a sandard SAP table! Its a Z table  :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
TYPES:
  BEGIN OF key_package_type,
    from TYPE primary_key_type,
    to   TYPE primary_key_type,
  END OF key_package_type.
TYPES key_packages_type TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF key_package WITH EMPTY KEY.
DATA key_packages TYPE key_packages_type.

* select only the primary keys, in packages
SELECT primary_key_column FROM db
    INTO TABLE @DATA(key_package) PACKAGE SIZE package_size
    WHERE cond IN @condition AND cond1 IN other_condition
    ORDER BY primary_key_column.

  INSERT VALUE #( from = key_package[ 1 ]-primary_key_column
                  to   = key_package[ lines( key_package ) ]-primary_key_column )
    INTO TABLE key_packages.

ENDSELECT.

* select the actual data by the primary key packages
LOOP AT key_packages INTO key_package.
  SELECT * FROM db INTO TABLE @DATA(result_package)
    WHERE primary_key_column >= key_package-from
      AND primary_key_column <= key_package-to.
  save_to_file( result_package ).
ENDLOOP.
```

If your table has a compound primary key, i.e. multiple columns such as {MANDT, GJAHR, BELNR}, simply replace the types of the `from` and `to` fields with structures and adjust the column list in the first SELECT and the WHERE condition in the second SELECT appropriately.

Comment: That's actually a very nice solution!

Comment: Very good solution! I just have one question in this solution which is, how to I select the different primary keys into different tables based on package size? Or is it better to select all primary keys and then split according to package size?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by „different primary keys“?

Comment: Just stumbled upon this excellent approach while doing research for a problem of my own and while implementing it something came up: 
In the actual data SELECT, aren't u missing the select conditions from the primary key selection ("WHERE con IN @condition AND ....")? Otherwise ur resulting data set has all records between the first matched and the last matched key. In the most extreme case this could be the entire database.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a range containing only `option = 'EQ'` records or one of the conditions has a foreign key you can simply start looping before you do the select to reduce the size of the resulting table and move the method call out of the open cursor.

## OPTION = 'EQ'

Here you just loop over the range:

```
LOOP AT so_cond ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<cond>).

   SELECT * FROM db
     INTO CORRESPONDING FIELDS OF TABLE rt_data
     WHERE cond  = <cond>-low.
     AND   cond1 IN so_cond1.

   save(rt_data).

ENDLOOP.
```

## Foreign Key

Looping over the range is not possible in this case since you cannot easily resolve the other options like `CP`. But you can get each value the range selects from the foreign keytab of cond. Then you loop over the resulting table and do the `SELECT` statement inside like above.

```
SELECT cond FROM cond_foreign_keytab
   WHERE cond IN @so_cond
   INTO TABLE @DATA(cond_values).

LOOP AT cond_values ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<cond>).

   SELECT * FROM db
     INTO CORRESPONDING FIELDS OF TABLE rt_data
     WHERE cond  = <cond>.
     AND   cond1 IN so_cond1.

   save(rt_data).

ENDLOOP.
```